# Angular2 persisting data between components

Tags: angular, routes

I have a search screen @ http://localhost/employee

User enter search criteria and an DI service will return the result, I also use pagination in there and keep track of the current page.

Let say, I have selected an employee with id=123 and angular routing take me to @ http://localhost/employee/123

What is the best way to go if, when I navigate back to search page, I still have the search result and the currently selected page number?

Comment: That's the role of the service. Store the page number and results in the service.

Comment: Store the service returned data into a property in service so you can initiate without any call

Comment: Thanks alot guys

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments,  a service is a solution to this problem.

A great alternative is using redux state management e.g. with the ngrx library. With this, you have on central/global immodifiable state (called store) that can be read by all components and changed via actions. Read more about this in the [ngrx docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md). It takes some time to get used to it but really pays off.